# How to make button repeatedly use it's command when clicked python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How do I make a button use it's command whenever it is active? For example, if you hold a repeating button for 1 second, it should have executed it's command about 250 to 1000 times already right? But with a regular button, it just executes it one time, until you release the mouse and click it again. How can I make a button like that? I currently have this with moving,

```
def up(player):
        x = 0
        y = -10
        c.move(player.rect,x,y)
    def down(player):
        x = 0
        y = 10
        c.move(player.rect,x,y)
    def left(player):
        x = -10
        y = 0
        c.move(player.rect,x,y)
    def right(player):
        x = 10
        y = 0
        c.move(player.rect,x,y)
    #functions are in a class called player
p = player(sx1=950,sy1=540,sx2=975,sy2=565)
lup = lambda : tk.after(50,p.up)
upbtn = Button(tk,width=3,height=2,text="↑",command=lup)
upbtn.pack()
upbtn.place(x=960,y=700)
mainloop()
```

I searched on the web, but it didn't show any results consistent with my problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `repeatdelay` and `repeatinterval` of `tkinter.Button`.

- `repeatdelay`, the number of milliseconds to wait before starting to repeat.
- `repeatinterval`, the number of milliseconds to be used between repeats

Simple demo code,

```py
from tkinter import *

def on_click():
    global count
    count += 1
    print(f'click {count}')

root = Tk()

count = 0
button = Button(root, text='Fire', repeatdelay=100, repeatinterval=100, command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: unknown option "-repeatinterval" happened if you use `ttk.Button`, not `tk.Button`

Comment: @user14354511: Please accept this answer if it worked for you.